# iOS10: I cannot get currentUserNotificationSettings after getting push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, ios10

I'm developing app using push notification, and I had an issue on only iOS10 devices.

I can get currentUserNotificatoinSettings.types during the first launch.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].currentUserNotificationSettings.types;
```

But after I got pushNotification, the thread, which read currentUserNotificatoinSettings.types, froze without any exceptions.
Somehow I tried to get exceptions by using @try@catch, breakpointNavigator in Xcode, or Zombies on profiler, but it doesn't show any exceptions.

How should I debug this issue? or does anyone know what the cause of this issue is?

Comment: Are you getting some Exception when iOS decode the payload in push notification?

Answer (score 0):

You should access `UIApplication` methods only from on main thread. Wrap your code that accesses the notification settings in a `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), …`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but I access currentUserNotificationSettings on main thread and so, my application freeze by it. Strange to say, this issue also happens on [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:] method after getting push notification... :(

Comment: What do you see in the stack trace? When app is stuck, pause in the debugger and add a screenshot of what can be seen there.

Comment: Here's mine: [link](https://prnt.sc/hkrl6i).
The app got frozen on this line after receiving a notification, although it IS a main thread for sure. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @demon9733 You need to open the stack trace to include the system frames, otherwise it's impossible to know what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved same problem on iOS 11.2.6. I provide [my system callstak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuHcY.png) when the app is stuck.
In my case, currentUserNotificationSettings called synchronously on main thread, not asynchronously. So that maybe causes deadlock.
I don't know why this is not occurred in iOS 12. But I hope this can help you. Thanks.